# Azure DocumentDB encryption at rest: using own encryption key?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

as a follow up to the twitter conversation here https://twitter.com/johannwalder/status/854791427871694848 is it possible to use our own encryption keys for the DocumentDB encryption at rest?

I have found the following answer "We are working on providing capabilities for customers to bring their own encryption keys." about storage service here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-service-encryption but not sure if the same applies to DocumentDB as well.

Thank you!

Best regards,
Johann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johann - DocumentDB is delivering "Encryption at Rest with Service Managed Keys."  As PaaS service we have done all the heavy lifting of managing keys and keeping them secure.  We have also worked with [auditors to ensure we are PCI compliant](http://www.dataarchitect.cloud/adding-offerings-and-uk-region-azure-rolls-deep-with-pci-dss-v3-2/) as are customers using our service.  I mention this because many customers ask for "Customer Managed Keys" as a proxy for meeting compliance requirements like PCI.

Happy to discuss any of the topics around Encryption At Rest (E@R) more in the coming ~week I'll be posting some detailed documentation.  Until then ... happy computing and thanks for using Azure DocumentDB.

Anthony F. Voellm [Microsoft Developer]
For context I'm the lead developer delivering the Encryption at Rest feature for DocumentDB.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for this clarification.

Best regards,
Johann